# Listbox, Order by file size

Tags: c#

I'm trying to populate a listbox with files from a directory, but I would like to order them by filesize. Where do I make that condition? Inisde the string or in the foreach statement?

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls")
         .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date >= DateTime.Today.Date 
                && file.Contains("AA"))
         .ToArray();

string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(FBD.SelectedPath);
foreach (string file in files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Comment: It's not clear how `dirs` is related to your issue. If it's not relevant to your question, please don't include it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "inside the string". What string? It really doesn't matter where you put it. In the foreach or as part of your query. Put it wherever makes more sense to someone maintaining your code.

Comment: You could just add: `.OrderBy(file => new FileInfo(file).Length)` after the `.Where()` clase to order by file size.

Comment: Or you could add: `foreach (string file in files.OrderBy(f => new FileInfo(f).Length))`

Comment: Use DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() instead so you can easily get the file length.  And glue an OrderByDescending clause in the Linq query.

Comment: By the way, `DateTime.Today` is the same as `DateTime.Today.Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your LINQ a bit.

1. Select the FileInfo first so that the subsequent LINQ clauses can access its properties
2. Filter on the FileInfo's name and date
3. Order by the FileInfo's length
4. Select the full path to convert back to a string

Example:

```
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls")
        .Select( path => new FileInfo(path) )
        .Where
        ( 
            info => info.CreationTime.Date >= DateTime.Today.Date 
                 && info.Name.Contains("AA") 
        )
        .OrderByDescending(info => info.Length )
        .Select( info => info.FullName )
        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` (or better yet, `.EnumerateFiles`) instead of `Directory` in this case, since you're interested in the extended file properties. This way you don't need to create multiple new `FileInfo` objects each time you want to check a file property (like `CreationTime` or `Length`):

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(FDB.SelectedPath)
    .EnumerateFiles("*.xls")
    .Where(file => file.CreationTime.Date >= DateTime.Today
                   && file.Name.Contains("AA"))
    .OrderBy(file => file.Length)
    .ToArray();
```

If you don't need the full `FileInfo` object properties after this initial query, then you can just select the `FullName` property to get an array of strings instead:

```
string[] files = new DirectoryInfo(FDB.SelectedPath)
    .EnumerateFiles("*.xls")
    .Where(file => file.CreationTime.Date >= DateTime.Today
                   && file.Name.Contains("AA"))
    .OrderBy(file => file.Length)
    .Select(file => file.FullName)  // Gets only the full path and file name
    .ToArray();
```